# Can one add boost program_options and parameters after CLI parsing is finished?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

The boost.program_options library stores and allows programmatic access to parameters provided on the command line when the program was run.

Is it practical to call some library function (unknown to me, or easy to code) to instantiate options/parameters, also change value parameters on an option, once the program is running and has already parsed all CLI arguments? In other words, could one simply fire up (ie. add) existing options already configured in the source code, but not mentioned at the time of invocation?

Why? Let's say the program has a GUI and the user wants to update some setting set at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to re-parse.

Dynamic adding of program_options_descriptions is more for the case that you have a plugin that adds additional options rather than for changing what has already been parsed. Or for taking several sets of options (basic, advanced, environment variable and config file sourced) and populating the variables_map.

options_description has an add() overload taking another options_description instance and adds the options from that instance to this. However, such an addition would not cause already parsed items in the variable_map to change.

Answer (score 0):

Re-starting the program would create a second process with a second command line. That's not a big problem, but you'll need inter-process communication to forward the second command line to the first process. Luckily boost also has [Boost.Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

Once your process has discovered that there's a pre-existing process, and has forwarded the second set of arguments, it can close. I'd do the re-processing of the command line options in the primary process.